# PHP/Javascript - Post data with unique ID's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an dynamic form with a add more button which creates an XML file that can be used for importing data.

The user fills out the form and can click more to add as many as they want. The data is then written to create a file via fwrite.

The problem is i'm using unique ID's and i need to get the values in order to create the file.

Here's the javascript
https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/mbfjmd02/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
      var s = String(this);
      while (s.length < (size || 0)) {s = "0" + s;}
      return s;
    }

    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    var c = 9;

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            c++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><label><span>Template Id :</span><input   type="text" name="templateid'+x+'" id="templateid'+x+'"></label><label><span>UNC Path :</span><input type="text" name="uncpath'+x+'" id="uncpath'+x+'"></label><label><span>Username :</span><input type="text" name="username'+x+'" id="username'+x+'"></label><label><span>Password :</span><input type="text" name="password'+x+'" id="password'+x+'"></label><label><span>Name :</span><input type="text" name="scantoname'+x+'" id="scantoname'+x+'"></label><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-primary">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box

            <!--add input value to "how many" field-->
            $.each($('input[name="howmany[]"]'), function() {
                $(this).val(x);
            });

            <!--add input value to "templateid" field-->
            $('input[name="templateid'+x+'"]').each(function() {
                $(this).val((x).pad(3,0));
            }); 
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

How do i post the data in PHP? I tried a bunch of stuff but its not working. :(

```
$templateid = @$_POST["templateid'+x+'"];
$uncpath = @$_POST["uncpath'+x+'"];
$username = @$_POST["username'+x+'"];
$password = @$_POST["password'+x+'"];
$scantoname = @$_POST["scantoname'+x+'"];


$f_data= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JobTemplates>
<GroupList>
<Group gid="000">
<MetaData>
<groupName>Public Template Group</groupName>
<userName />
<isPasswordProtected>false</isPasswordProtected>
<ownerName>Admin</ownerName>
<notificationEmail />
<TemplateCount>'.$templateid.'</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>'.$uncpath.'</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>'.$username.'</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>'.$password.'</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>'.$scantoname.'</TemplateCount>';
```

The end goal is to get a file that looks like this:

```
<JobTemplates>
<GroupList>
<Group gid="000">
<MetaData>
<groupName>Public Template Group</groupName>
<userName />
<isPasswordProtected>false</isPasswordProtected>
<ownerName>Admin</ownerName>
<notificationEmail />
<TemplateCount>001</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>\\test\test</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>bill</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>pass</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>bill crab</TemplateCount>
<JobTemplates>
<GroupList>
<Group gid="000">
<MetaData>
<groupName>Public Template Group</groupName>
<userName />
<isPasswordProtected>false</isPasswordProtected>
<ownerName>Admin</ownerName>
<notificationEmail />
<TemplateCount>002</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>\\test\test2</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>Mike</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>pass</TemplateCount>
<TemplateCount>Mike crab</TemplateCount>';
```

Comment: you have to get the `gid` form xml and use-it in php or _vice versa_?

Comment: writing the xml is not a problem, i just need the values from the form.

Comment: can you generate a random id of your choosing? ie a random number based upon time or use php `uniqid()` or are they to be sequential digits 001,002,003 etc?

Comment: They need to be sequential because of the backend XML program its going to be used for

Comment: I notice all of your attempts to pull stuff from the $_POST array include a string  of the form: ``"someTextHere'+x+'"`` -this will evaluate to literally and exactly the same thing! Why? Because the whole thing's wrapped in quotes of one type - the other type of quotes are then stored as part of the string - they're _not_ white-space/operator delimiters. The other thing I notice, is that there's no reference to an `x` variable in your displayed code, except in the JS - you're not trying to get the value that _this_ `x` had, are you? Lastly, look into POSTing an array of things to PHP.

Comment: By posting arrays you can post a single array with all of the templateId fields, another with all of the uncpath fields and so on. By naming (name='xxx[]') your html elements with text that includes array brackets, you achieve this. You can then not care about the element's ID when it comes time to retrieve it on the PHP side - you only care about the values of the `templateid` array elements - you can index all of the fields of any particular collection using the same index. I.e `$tmpIds = $_POST['templateid']; $uncpaths = $_POST['uncpaths']. $item1_id = $tmpIds[0]; $item1_unc = uncpaths[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here'e a fully worked example, expanding upon what I mentioned earlier in my comments. Firstly, take note of the very different way I'm creating a new bunch of inputs when the user asks for them - I'm adding them all as elements, rather than as a text string. Secondly, I'm defining the fields I want in an array - this makes adding to or changing these fields very much quicker, easier and less error-prone.

Next, you can see if you examine the generated html, that the inputs only have names, there's just no need to give them IDs in this case.

Finally, you can see the PHP which simply echoes back the contents of the $_POST array.

**blank.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var nextIdToUseGlobal = 0;

function onDocLoaded()
{
    addFormElems( byId('fieldContainer'), nextIdToUseGlobal++ );
}

function addFormElems(fieldContainer, idToUse)
{
    var formItems = [
                        {type: 'input', name: 'ids[]', label: 'Template Id:'},
                        {type: 'input', name: 'uncs[]', label: 'Unc Path:'},
                        {type: 'input', name: 'usernames[]', label: 'Username:'},
                        {type: 'input', name: 'passwords[]', label: 'Password:'},
                    ];

    formItems.forEach( formElemForEachFunc );
    fieldContainer.appendChild( newEl('hr') );

    function formElemForEachFunc(elem, index, list)
    {
        var curField = newEl( elem.type );
        curField.setAttribute('name', elem.name);
        if (index == 0)                             // 0 since this is the index of the id field in the above array
            curField.value = idToUse;
        fieldContainer.appendChild( newTxt(elem.label) );
        fieldContainer.appendChild( curField );
        fieldContainer.appendChild( newEl('br') );
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='addFormElems(byId("fieldContainer"),nextIdToUseGlobal++)'>Add new Scan Item</button><br>
    <form id='myForm' action='outputTest.php' method='post'>
        <div id='fieldContainer'></div>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit values'/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**outputTest.php**

```
<?php
    var_dump( $_POST );

    $numItems = count( $_POST["ids"] );     // get number of items in the ids array
    $ids = $_POST["ids"];
    $uncs = $_POST["uncs"];
    $users = $_POST["usernames"];
    $passwords = $_POST["passwords"];

    echo("<hr>");
    echo("You submitted $numItems items for scanning" . "<hr>");

    for ($i=0; $i<$numItems; $i++)
    {
        echo "ID: $ids[$i]" . "<br>";
        echo "UNC: $uncs[$i]" . "<br>";
        echo "username: $users[$i]" . "<br>";
        echo "password: $passwords[$i]" . "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you dont have a **form** tag in your HTML code, then I believe that's the problem that your PHP code is not receiving anything.

Create a form tag that encapsulate all your fields then it should work.

I would suggest you to remove those "@" from your POST array, so you can see what your form is submitting to PHP or even if something is being submitted.

**Update**
Like enhzflep said, you are trying to access keys on your POST array that doesnt exist.
Why are you using:

```
@$_POST["templateid'+x+'"];
```

The key used in POST should be the exact same name your form's input name is.
If you are not sure about what the names are, try using

```
print_r($_POST);
```

or

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Do that and you will understand better what is going on.

Comment: Sorry that i didnt include the form tag but its there: <form name="myform" action="save.php" method="post" class="white-pink">

Comment: when i run the following, i'm only getting one value:     $scantoname = $_POST["scantoname"];

echo implode(" ",$scantoname);

Comment: Can you post your HTML ?

Comment: check your console.log after creating. there are some javascript errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach, instead of using javascript to generate the number values (+x+) lets just do it with php so there's not an issue:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
foreach($_POST['howmany'] as $item_number){
  $item_number = $item_number;
}   

for($x=1;$x<=$item_number;$x++){
    echo $_POST["templateid".$x]; 
     echo '<br>';
}


 for($x=1;$x<=$item_number;$x++){
  echo $_POST["templateid".$x];  
  echo '<br>';
  echo $_POST["uncpath".$x]; 
   echo '<br>';
  echo $_POST["username".$x]; 
   echo '<br>';
  echo $_POST["password".$x]; 
   echo '<br>';
  echo $_POST["scantoname".$x]; 
   echo '<br>';
 }
}
?>
```